# updating a BLOB column ,ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: oracle

I want to store a procedure in a BLOB column, unfortunatly I cannot show you the code but it contain 126 lines. This is the update I am using

```
DECLARE   str varchar2(20000);
BEGIN   str :='create or replace A_LONG_PROCEDURE  procedure .........';
UPDATE tab1 SET  report=str
WHERE reference= 'TER';
commit;
end;
/
```

I got error `ORA-01461; can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`

I tried using update .. `set ='CREATE OR REPLACE LONG_PROCEDURE ...'` I Get error 01704 string litteral to long

How to update a long procedure into a blob column ?

Comment: just checking , is my answer clear or it need more explanation ?

Comment: try `declare str tab1.report%type;`

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss I got an error wrong type of expression , the column type of report is blob

Comment: `str:= to_blob('383838');`  see documentation to `to_blob`, input is `raw` type. why do you use blob and not clob datatype?

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss it didnt work i made it like this `str := to_blob(rawtohex('` and i got error ora-06502 numeric or value error: hex to raw conversion error

Comment: `str:= to_blob(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('create or replace A_LONG_PROCEDURE...'));` should work

Comment: WHY do you want to store a procedure in a BLOB column? That makes no sense. BLOB is for binary (raw, executable) data. A stored procedure, no matter how long, is a character string. The CLOB data type is for this kind of data. The solution is simple: alter your table to change the column type from BLOB to CLOB. Even if there are ways to save a long string into a BLOB column, that makes no sense!

Comment: @mathguy useally they store xml and report files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, consider of changing column to clob.

```
DECLARE   
  declare str tab1.report%type;
BEGIN   
  str:= to_blob(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('create or replace     A_LONG_PROCEDURE...'));

  UPDATE tab1 SET  report=str
  WHERE reference= 'TER';

  commit;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change column type to `CLOB` or initialize `CLOB` variable to procedure text and after that convert it to `BLOB` with [`dbms_lob.ConvertToBlob`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i1020355) procedure before inserting.

Sample for Oracle 11g:

Table setup:

```
create table lob_sample(
  id         number,
  clob_field clob,
  blob_field blob
);

insert into lob_sample(id) values(1);
```

Code:

```
declare 
  vSomeLongString varchar2(32767);
  vClob CLOB;          
  vBlob BLOB;
begin

  -- Build sample string from all_objects view
  for cFill in (
    select object_type||' '||owner||'.'||object_name||'; '||chr(10) sample_string
    from all_objects
  ) loop                                              

    vSomeLongString := vSomeLongString || cFill.sample_string;
    if(length(vSomeLongString) > 32000) then exit; end if;
  end loop;                                       


  -- String may be directly assigned to CLOB
  vClob := vSomeLongString;

  -- And it's possible to simple assign CLOB variable value to CLOB field 
  update lob_sample set clob_field = vClob where id = 1;

  -- Even, string value may be directly assigned to CLOB field
  update lob_sample set clob_field = vSomeLongString where id = 1;

  -- But for BLOB field conversion are needed.     
  -- BLOB is just a set of raw bytes and it may present 
  -- any character set as well as non-text data.
  dbms_lob.CreateTemporary(vBlob, false);                       
  declare
    vDestOffset  integer := 1;
    vSrcOffset   integer := 1;
    vDefaultCSID number  := dbms_lob.default_csid;
    vLangContext integer := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
    vWarning     integer;
  begin               
    dbms_lob.convertToBlob(
      vBlob, vClob, dbms_lob.LobMaxSize,
      vDestOffset, vSrcOffset, vDefaultCSID, vLangContext, vWarning
    );  
  end;  

  update lob_sample set blob_field = vBlob where id = 1;

  dbms_lob.freetemporary(vBlob);

end;
```

Comment: you mean convert str to clob ?...  can you post an example